# Is it OK to use a DataReader after disposing the Command object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datareader, oledbdatareader

I have created a small class of helper methods for working against a database. I'm wondering about this method:

```
Shared Function GetReader(sql As String, con As OleDbConnection) As OleDbDataReader

   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
   Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
   cmd.Dispose()
   Return reader

End Function
```

Am I going to run into some kind of trouble disposing the Command object first, then using the DataReader?

I'd prefer to keep calling code tidy by not creating/disposing Command objects all the time (seems redundant when that can be wrapped up in the helper method above).

Comment: Incidentally, from a design point of view, I am not overly worried about returning a DataReader to calling code. The helper methods won't be used outside of low-level database code. I.e. the Data Access Layer won't see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I going to run into some kind of trouble disposing the Command
>   object first, then using the DataReader?

No

But this is a cleaner code:

```
Shared Function GetReader(sql As String, con As OleDbConnection) As OleDbDataReader

   Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
      Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
      'cmd.Dispose() 'Not needed here, will be invoked automatically
      Return reader
   End Using

End Function
```

Side notes:

- Consider using `Using Statements` always for making sure all resources have been released
- Consider disposing the connection and reader once you are not needing them anymore. And don't be scared of closing then re-opening the connection again as connections are kept in a pool by default, and you should close them as soon as possible - especially if your application is under some form of load -

Answer (score 0):

Their is nothing wrong with this snippet, Before executing `cmd.Dispose()` you ware assigning the query result to the reader ie., `Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader` so reader having the result even after disposing the `cmd`. and it will hold the value till the connection get `closed` or else  `reader .Dispose()` occures.